# Can somebody check this normalisation works - I think I am missing a step or a dependency somewhere

Tags: database-design, normalization

Given these two tables:

[image]

and:

[image]

I need to first list them as an un-normalised structure(s), then I need to identify the functional dependencies/primary keys.

Once I have done this I must represent it in 3NF. I think I am skipping 1NF and going straight to 2NF, but I can't work out the intermediate step.

#### Un-normalised structures with PKs

```
Piste (PisteName {PK}, Grade, Length, Fall, Lifts (repeating group), Open)
Lift (LiftName {PK}, LiftType, Rise, Length, Operating)
```

#### Functional dependencies

```
PisteName →{Grade, Length, Fall, Open}
LiftName →{LiftType, Rise, Length, Operating}
```

Is there any more? I can't seem to see any.

### Normalisation:

#### 1NF

```
Piste (PisteName, Grade, Length, Fall,  Open)
Lift (LiftName, LiftType, Rise, Length, Operating)
LiftLocation (PiestName*, LiftName*)
```

Now from what I can tell this is 1NF, 2NF and 3NF so I have obviously missed something because the teacher is expecting us to show the steps for each NF.

Can anybody point me in the right direction/and or tell me where I've messed up?

Comment: I think you are fine. You can add how you check that the result of your 1NF normalization is actually already in 2NF and then why it is in 3NF. Not simply ("Now from what i can tell this is 1NF, 2NF and 3NF") but what exactly your checking conditions are.

Comment: @ypercube 1NF is no repeating groups, 2NF is no partial dependencies and 3NF is no transitive dependencies. Which to me seems to be correct. I keep having a feeling i've missed something because it quotes "show you workings to 3NF" so when i put it into 1NF it is already in 2NF and 3NF, then surely ive missed something maybe a dependency?